# range() on QuerySet for tqdm on QuerySet

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am trying to add a progress bar to a loop of Django objects. So I need to put the list (QuerySet) in `range()` so I can get the number of total loop iteration.

Code:

```
rows = DjangoObjects.objects.all()
for i in tqdm(range(rows)):
    row = rows[i]
    ...
```

Error:

```
range() integer end argument expected, got QuerySet.
```

Code attempt #2:

```
rows = DjangoObjects.objects.all()
for row in tqdm(rows):
    ...
```

Error:

```
Exception AttributeError: "'tqdm' object has no attribute 'disable'" in <object repr() failed> ignored
```

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why? tqdm() takes any iterable, you don't have to use range(). If you need an index in your loop, use enumerate().

Edit:
Have you read [tqdm documentation](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm)? There's everything there. You're iterating over tqdm objects. If you need both tqdm and your query results in your loop, do something like this:

```
with tqdm(total=len(rows)) as pbar:
    for row in rows:
        # Do whatever with your query result
        pbar.update(1)
```

Comment: Added the error with the attempt of passing the queryset into tqdm

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```py
from tqdm import tqdm

your_queryset = YourModel.objects.all()
with tqdm(total=your_queryset.count()) as t:
    for object in your_queryset:
        # Do something
        t.update(1)
```